# Trouble getting tcpdump to capture data from android

Tags: bash, tcpdump, monkey

I'm trying to write a bash script in Ubuntu to install an app on an android emulator, send random commands to the app using 'monkey' and capture all the data with tcpdump. 
Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#store all apks files in array
shopt -s nullglob
packageArray=(*.apk)


function getPackageName()
{
    myResult= aapt dump badging $1 | grep package | awk '{print $2}' | sed   s/name=//g | sed s/\'//g
}

#loop through array installing, testing and capturing data, and uninstalling
for i in "${packageArray[@]}";
do
    :
    myResult=$(getPackageName "$i")

echo "------------------INSTALLING-----------------"

sudo adb install $i
echo "*****************INSTALLED****************************"

echo "*****************TESTING****************************"

#-------THESE COMMANDS ARE THE TROUBLE-------

(sudo -i xterm -e "tcpdump src 10.0.2.11 -vvv >   /home/seed/Documents/autoTcpLogs/$myResult.pcap" &
sudo -i xterm -e "adb shell monkey -p $myResult -v 500")
echo "------------------DONE TESTING-----------------"

sudo adb uninstall $myResult
echo "*****************PACKAGE UNINSTALLED****************************"

done
```

The Problem: I need a good way for tcpdump to close once monkey has completed sending the 500 random commands. I've tried using the KILL command in a few different ways, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: have you tried `killall -TERM tcpdump` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it after the monkey command.

Comment: See the answer. The PID of tcpdump is stored in a variable and used as `kill` argument. If it fails, update your question with the reason of the failure (save the kill command output somewhere and paste it here)

Comment: Humm, nevermind, you're using `sudo` and the stored PID will be of `sudo`, not the `tcpdump` process.

Comment: Definitely a good thought though, there might be some variation which will lead to success

Comment: yes, let me think a bit. I'll remove the answer for now and perform some testing.

Comment: You could use `sudo blah &` and then `sudo kill $SUDO_PID`

Comment: Will you have only one tcpdump running? Or there may be multiple tcpdumps running at any given time?

Comment: @Barmar that will kill `sudo`, but not the `tcpdump` process. I also though that sudo would route the signal to the child process, but that, unfurtunatelly, doesn't occur.

Comment: I think it should also kill all the children of sudo. I tried it with `sudo sleep 100 &` and it killed `sleep` as well.

Comment: I will run tcpdump, run monkey (while tcpdump captures all the data being emitted from the emulator), and then close tcpdump. So only 1 at a time.

Comment: @Barmar yep, you're right. Also checked the manpage and clearly states that it relays some signals (including SIGTERM) to the child... but now the odd part is that my answer script should work regardless sudo being used or not... and that's not happening... I'm performing some debugs and will update it whenever I got a proper answer.

Comment: As another solution, I just realized I could set tcpdump to only capture a specific amount of packets before exiting, which would ensure I get all the data I want w/o overlapping tcpdump files.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -- tcpdump > /dev/null &
SUDO_TCPDUMP_PID=$!
echo "Waiting 3 seconds"
sleep 3;
echo "3 seconds elapsed"
sudo -- setsid kill -TERM "${SUDO_TCPDUMP_PID}"
```

**EDIT** (read question comments): We need to use `setsid` to force the signal to be sent from a different session, otherwise `sudo` will not relay the signal (see `sudo` manpage).

The PID of `sudo tcpdump ...` (the `sudo` pid in this case) will be stored in the `SUDO_TCPDUMP_PID` variable, which will be used as `kill` argument:

```
$ ./tcp.sh
Waiting 3 seconds
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
3 seconds elapsed
0 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
$
```